# How can I determine matches across columns for each row using custom-specified criteria for matching?

Tags: r, match

I need to identify matches across columns that include different value labels for the same result for each row in a dataframe. For example, in column A in the dataframe below the terms "yes" and "no" are used - but - in column B the terms "affirmative" and "negative" are used. I need to find a way to indicate "match" when the column A value is "yes" and the column B value is "affirmative" - or - when the column A value is "no" and the column B value is "negative". I need to also indicate "fail" when those conditions do not occur.

In other words, I am looking for code that would yield the result in the "match_result" column in the sample data below:

```
id <- seq(1, 10)
A <- c(rep("yes", 3), rep("no", 3), rep("yes", 3), "no")
B <- c(rep("affirmative", 5), rep("negative", 5))
match_result <- c(rep("match", 3), rep("fail", 2), "match", rep("fail", 
3), "match")

dat <- data.frame(id, A, B, match_result)
dat

 id   A           B                  match_result
 1    yes         affirmative        match
 2    yes         affirmative        match
 3    yes         affirmative        match
 4    no          affirmative        fail
 5    no          affirmative        fail
 6    no          negative           match
 7    yes         negative           fail
 8    yes         negative           fail
 9    yes         negative           fail
10    no          negative           match
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only two variation of values to compare, we can create a logical condition

```
dat$match_result1 <- c("fail", "match")[with(dat, 
         A == "yes" & B == "affirmative" | A == "no" & B == "negative") + 1]

dat
#   id   A           B match_result match_result1
#1   1 yes affirmative        match         match
#2   2 yes affirmative        match         match
#3   3 yes affirmative        match         match
#4   4  no affirmative         fail          fail
#5   5  no affirmative         fail          fail
#6   6  no    negative        match         match
#7   7 yes    negative         fail          fail
#8   8 yes    negative         fail          fail
#9   9 yes    negative         fail          fail
#10 10  no    negative        match         match
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `+ 1` is for at the end?

Comment: @PeterMiksza `A == "yes" & B == "affirmative" | A == "no" & B == "negative"` this condition returns a logical vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values. By adding `+ 1` we are converting `TRUE` from 1 to 2 and `FALSE` from 0 to 1 which is then used to subset `"fail (1)"` and `"match (2)"`

Comment: if I wanted to add a third condition such that I would require that three variables match - would I just add it like this: `A == "yes" & B == "affirmative" & C == "yep" I A == "no" & B == "negative" & C == "nope"` ??

Comment: @PeterMiksza If you have lot of conditions then better to use `ifelse` or `case_when` from `dplyr`. It would be clear and easy to understand.